# How can I find records that have the same values in a ManyToMany field in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

These are the models:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)

class Subscription(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    user = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='subscriptions')
    posts = models.ManyToManyField(Post, related_name='subscriptions')
```

I want to find all the users that are subscribed to the same posts so that I can send them the same email instead of creating a different email for each user.

The code should basically list all the times in Subscription that have the same values in the posts field.

I spent the last four hours on this, googling the heck out of this but to no avail.

I'm confiding in the *Force*, which is strong on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like below,

```
In [88]: posts = Subscription.objects.filter(posts=1)

In [89]: for post in posts:
    ...:     print(post.user)
    ...:
    ...:
Gokul
john
```